# What advantages does a SSD with a DRAM possess?

Tags: memory, ssd, data-storage, upgrade

My current system is dell inspiron 15 core i5 7th gen 5567, 8GB RAM,1TB HDD. I'm upgrading it with 500GB SSD and 8 GB RAM.

Take my example, I'm a CS graduate trying to learn full stack web development.

My usage of laptop would be learning from videos, reading articles and writing code in IDEs and running them. I'm getting lots of DRAM-less SSDs for a good price, so I'm wondering if I should grab them or not. Are there any benefits that a SSD with DRAM would offer me?

I'm hearing that DRAM-less SSDs wear and tear quickly and could be slower as well.

The reason for having to learn this information is because I'm not getting other good SSDs in my country like MX500 of Crucial or 870 EVO of Samsung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRAM less SSD's are indeed generally slower and generally do wear out faster. Because of this, I reccomend getting some more money and get the MX500. Regardless of your SSD choice (all are better that a hard drive). I reccomend installing Linux since it's easier  to install some servers for web devving like Apache and PHP (those only run on Linux AFAIK). Seeing how old your CPU is, VMs are not really handy.

Comment: So, I can't use Windows anymore(for VM)? Then I see no point of doing this upgrade. Is a core i5 that old already? Even new laptops mostly use core i7 CPU.

Comment: You can do Windows + VM but it's gonna be more laggy, since your i5 is pre coffee lake.

Comment: Especially with only one HDD/SSD, since both OSses need to access the same disk

Comment: https://askmitra.com/question/cpu-requirements-to-use-a-virtual-machine-in-windows-10/#comment-10613

people here are saying otherwise.

Comment: If I get 16GB RAM, would it run fine? Is there a point of upgrading this laptop for my purpose? My budget is constrained.

Comment: Should run okay, just slow (very slow if you do GUI)